# how to findelement using android INTEGER Id (and not name of the Id) in appium project?

Tags: android, appium

I am unable to find the element of a android project as I don't have ID NAME because all views are dynamically generated and Ids are set as bellow

```
view.setId(50);
```

How to find element in this case?

"package_name:id/50" is not working.

Comment: i am not sure if this is possible